# Is there a function in R to delete the last comma in a JSON file?

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I am fairly new to R, and I have a large folder of JSON files that need to have the trailing comma removed. I have seen a lot of other suggestions in other languages, but would like to keep my code in R.

[image: The end of each JSON file]

The trailing comma is the only issue, as I manually deleted it and there were no other errors in the code.

Comment: Welcome to SO, user21117870! Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., minimal otherwise-complete contents of the json string) directly.

Comment: According to a [JSON validator](https://jsonlint.com/) that syntax is not a valid so it's not really correct to call the JSON files. I guess they are JSON-like files. Are you working with javascript code?

Answer (score 2):

Using this example file with a trailing comma:

```
writeLines(
'{
    "entry1": {
        "id": 1,
        "language": "en",
    }
}',
'file.json'
)
```

Read the file in as text, use a regex to remove commas followed by `}`, write the corrected file back to disk, then read in again as JSON:

```
library(stringr)
library(jsonlite)

readLines("file.json") |>
  paste(collapse = "\n") |>
  str_remove_all(",(?=\\n\\s*\\})") |>
  writeLines("file_fixed.json")

read_json("file_fixed.json")
```

Or if you don’t want to save corrected versions to disk, skip that step and use `fromJSON()`:

```
readLines("file.json") |>
  paste(collapse = "\n") |>
  str_remove_all(",(?=\\n\\s*\\})") |>
  fromJSON()
```

Result:

```
$entry1
$entry1$id
[1] 1

$entry1$language
[1] "en"
```

Comment: Right you are - edited, thanks!